# how to encode contents of __doPostBack() function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, dopostback

For example:

```
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PlaceHolderMain$g_188da349_7fe9_42f0_9a95_40cee6cd37a4$ctl00$ctl05$lbtnApplicationName','')">
```

What are this contents behind call?

Comment: Sorry! Could not decipher your question. Wish it can be elaborated.

Comment: The body of the question suggests that you want to decode rather than encode, the question is however rather hard to... decode. 

This is an ASP.NET JavaScript postback, [most likely] what should happen when a LinkButton named lbtnApplicationName has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the HTML sent to the browser for "server side" link button:

```html
<asp:LinkButton id="lbtnApplicationName" runat="server" OnClick="SomeFuncHere" Text="Get Application Name" />
```

And this button is inside unnamed control that is named `ctl05` by default, and is inside other control that also has no name thus got the default name `ctl00` etc.. etc.. etc..

In general, the `ASP.NET` framework is building the final ID of element based on its direct ID and chaining the ID of its parent controls - content placeholders included.
For form elements, their `name` is built in similar way with the exception that instead of `_`, it's using `$` to "chain" the ID of the parents.

Why? To avoid the possibility of having more than one element with same ID in the same HTML document. (Or two form elements with same name when they're in different controls)

Now this final ID is used to tell the server what control invoked the PostBack - this is done using JavaScript function written to the page automatically by the framework that get the ID of the element as its argument.